# How to call a static class method from another method of the same class?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to work with Octave and I couldn't find how to run some scripts that uses functions of a file, the last thing I tried was creating a class, but without success. The problem is some functions have inside anothers functions. For example:

```
classdef ALLFUNCS
   methods(Static)
      function result = SumElements(a,b,c)
          result = a + b + c;
      end
      function [prod,div] = MultiplyDivide(v1,v2,v3)
          prod = v1 * v2 * v3;
          div  = v1 / v2 / v3;
      end
      function resulta = powelents(a,b,c)
        pas = SumElements(a,b,c);
        resulta = pas*pas;
      end 
   end
end
```

In the command line I put

```
s2 = ALLFUNCS.powelents(3,4,5);
```

The error is:

```
error: 'SumElements' undefined near line 11 column 19
error: called from
powelents at line 11 column 17
```

So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: please note that octave has limited support for the so-called "new" object-oriented style (i.e. the one that uses 'classdef' keyword as opposed to the old way of organising classes via '@'-prefixed folders). See the octave wiki for details: https://wiki.octave.org/Classdef and also the relevant section on the manual: https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/classdef-Classes.html

Answer (score 5):

Functions declared within a Methods Block are bound to their defining class (if static) or instances of the defining class (if not static). They don't have the typical Local Function scoping rules as in other contexts.

Therefore, the following line within the implementation of `powelents`

```
pas = SumElements(a,b,c);
```

does not have knowledge of the `SumElements` method (lexically) defined above `powelents`, so Octave and MATLAB will look for a `SumElements` on the search path in the global namespace and not find one.

The solution is to invoke the method using the class itself

```
function resulta = powelents(a,b,c)
    pas = ALLFUNCS.SumElements(a,b,c);
    resulta = pas*pas;
end
```

This tells the run-time where to find the function definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is like Octave first search the main file and then the function.